# How to save API response to csv with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, response

I'm getting facedetection data from an API in this form:

```
{"id":1,"ageMin":0,"ageMax":100,"faceConfidence":66.72220611572266,"emotion":"ANGRY","emotionConfidence":50.0'
b'2540969848633,"eyeglasses":false,"eyeglassesConfidence":50.38102722167969,"eyesOpen":true,"eyesOpenConfidence":50.20328140258789'
b',"gender":"Male","genderConfidence":50.462989807128906,"smile":false,"smileConfidence":50.15522384643555,"sunglasses":false,"sun'
b'glassesConfidence":50.446510314941406}]'
```

I'd like to save this to a csv-file like this:

```
id  ageMin  ageMax  faceConfidence
1   0       100     66
```

... and so on.
I tried to do it this way:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    with open('detections.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for item in response:
            writer.writerow(str(item))
```

That puts every char in its own cell. I've also tried to use `item.id`, but that gives an error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'id'`.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Your response is JSON-formatted. Python doesn't automatically turn JSON strings to objects, hence why you're getting that `AttributeError`. Parse the string with the `json` library before attempting to access the object's properties.

Comment: To get json response, use `response.json()` than reading and converting to json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe an overkill for a small task, but you can do the following:

1. convert JSON response (do not forget to check exceptions, etc.) to python dictionary

   dic = response.json()
2. Create a dataframe, for example using pandas:

   df = pandas.DataFrame(dic)
3. Save to csv omitting index:

   df.to_csv('detections.csv', index=False, sep="\t")

Answer (score 3):

You can do this relatively easily with the pandas and json libraries.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

response = """{
    "id": 1,
    "ageMin": 0,
    "ageMax": 100,
    "faceConfidence": 66.72220611572266,
    "emotion": "ANGRY",
    "emotionConfidence": 50.0,
    "eyeglasses": false,
    "eyeglassesConfidence": 50.38102722167969,
    "eyesOpen": true,
    "eyesOpenConfidence": 50.20328140258789,
    "gender": "Male",
    "genderConfidence": 50.462989807128906,
    "smile": false,
    "smileConfidence": 50.15522384643555,
    "sunglasses": false,
    "glassesConfidence":50.446510314941406
}"""

file = json.loads(doc)

json = pd.DataFrame({"data": file})
json.to_csv("response.csv")
```

This is the response formatted to csv.

```
,data
ageMax,100
ageMin,0
emotion,ANGRY
emotionConfidence,50.0
eyeglasses,False
eyeglassesConfidence,50.38102722167969
eyesOpen,True
eyesOpenConfidence,50.20328140258789
faceConfidence,66.72220611572266
gender,Male
genderConfidence,50.462989807128906
glassesConfidence,50.446510314941406
id,1
smile,False
smileConfidence,50.15522384643555
sunglasses,False
```